# Dual-issue scheduling in MIPS

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

Here are the MIPS code:

```
Loop: lw   $t0, 0($s1)      # $t0=array element
      addu $t0, $t0, $s2    # add scalar in $s2
      sw   $t0, 4($s1)      # store result
      addi $s1, $s1,–4      # decrement pointer
      bne  $s1, $zero, Loop # branch $s1!=0
```

After scheduling, we can pack them like below:
[image]

Why addi instruction can move before the sw instruction?
They both use the $s1 register.
Before scheduling in the first iteration,we will get 0($s1)-> $t0, 4($s1)<- $t0+$s2.
However the scheduling result may be 0($s1)-> $t0, 0($s1)<- $t0+$s2
There are obviously different.
What I guess there is a magic in pipeline.
I don't know what the name is,so I call it "anti-data hazard".
Since addi instruction will write back in the 5th stage(WB), we could use the data hazard to make the sw instruction get the old data address($s1) in stage3.
(sw instruction will not trigger forwarding)
Is my guess right?Please tell me.

Comment: Who did the scheduling?  It doesn't seem right.

Comment: That transformation only works if the store addressing mode is changed to `8($s1)` to preserve the memmove+add behaviour.  Also, shouldn't a dual-issue pipeline be able to do the `addi $s1, $s1,–4` in parallel with the load, with the load using the original `s1` value because they run in parallel?  (In the asm source it would be lw / addi)

Comment: Or perhaps the original code was buggy, and it was *supposed* to be updating elements in-place, with the `4($s0)` actually intended to balance out doing the `s0 -= 4` before the store.